# How do I set up OAuth2.0 Request Headers

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I wanted to put a value, like postman, on the SpringDoc Swagger page, and apply it to all requests

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saN8X.png)

[swagger-ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwV1h.png)

And swagger is not expected to pop up an input popup for user names and passwords.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Github, I got the answer

[github](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/740#event-3463910617)